# Raspberry pi - java - Serial Com

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, raspbian

I've got a serious problem with my Raspberry Pi (OS: Raspbian) and Java (JDK-7-Armhf). My code wont execute without creating a Exception.
I'll been reading and trying several proposals and nothing have worked yet.
So now i am confused of what went wrong..?
So it goes like this:
I've got a Java source code that will run in my Eclipes IDE. 
But when i export the .jar-file, even with library (JRE System lib. _86, JavaSE1.7, JAVAX.comm), as "Runnabel JAR" or just .JAR and execute it om my Raspberry pi, i've got "NoCLassDefFoundExecption: SerialPortEventListener..! 
I just don't know why, it won't find the library and use it..!
On my Pi i have librxtx-java installed and JDK-7-oracle-armhf.
librxtx-java should be setting its JAVA_PATH on it's own when installed, but not sure that is done correct!
(I've got a folder /usr/jni and it contains: librxtxSerial.so and
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/).

Looking at the library Javax.RXTXcomm in Eclipse, i've got RXTXcomm.jar, that contains SerialPortEventListener, so it is defininated i the .jar.
I'm thinking about, could it be, that there is a missing link between my Java JVM and linux serialport driver? My JRE is working in some way, because it will execute a code to readout HOSTNAME & IP-Adress. 
So is there some one who knows how to fix this..?

This is a readout of Java Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/comm/SerialPortEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

[A copy of my code. "SimpleRead.java" The original from java comm API samples](http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/java/commapi/samples/Simple/SimpleRead.java)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the reference from javax.comm to gnu.io in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. Switch to root and run the program you created
2. If that helps do following
      `sudo adduser username dialout`
    then log out and log in from all terminals and GUIs

Comment: 1: No different with sudo. Exactly the same Exception.
2: User is already members of 'dialout'

Comment: sorry to hear that this did not help :(

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/CommConnection.html have you taken look at this? There is a major difference between java on pc and java on pi, look for java mobile serial communication

Comment: Yes.
The code i have should be able to be executed as it is on Pi, so fort i can see. Other user have used it on Raspberry Pi Raspbian-distro. But they other users simply have all other problems, than mine. I have been reading so many suggestions here on Stackoverflow, that i've got squared eyes..!

Now i'm considering to dumb Java as a "Alwayes conflicting Language with not much help to get" and get ongoing with some Python.
At least Python can do a simple task as communicate with a serialport. :-)

Comment: No not at all.
Did create a code that will detect I/O-ports and it works on my Window XP, it will find the diiferent COM-Ports and print it out on screen. But when running the code at my Pi, it just run the code, but apparently i won't find any ports at all.
And i can't figure it out. Have been reading a lot, but either people have another issue with serial I/O or it's a instrucs that assume that the communication with I/O is okay. 
The wird part is, a Python script on the same Pi, have no trouble at all and will send / recieve over /dev/ttyAMA0
Kind of stuck now :-(